# C# WinForms cannot send email

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp

I hava an application made in c# winforms, with is connected to a DB, i have a reste password function, but i always get an email whie trying to send it, such as `Failed to send email: Failure sending mail`. Here is my code

```
  public void SendEmail(string recipientEmail)
        {
            string smtpServer = "db-stud***.***";
            int smtpPort = 25; // or the appropriate port for your email server
            string smtpUsername = "no-reply@db-stud***.***";
            string smtpPassword = "***ra***";

            using (var message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@db-stud***.***");
                message.To.Add(recipientEmail);
                message.Subject = "Password Reset";

                var bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("Hello, dear User!");
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine();
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("Looks like you requested a password reset! If you did not request this, you can safely ignore this email.");
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("Unfortunately, at the moment your account does not support resetting your password by email, but we can offer you your password back:");
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine();
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("Your account password is:          ");
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine();
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("If you did not initiate this request, please ignore this email.");
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine();
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("Best regards,");
                bodyBuilder.AppendLine("     My Application name");

                message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToString();

                using (var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, smtpPort))
                {
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Host = "188.212.***.**";
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                    client.Timeout = 5000; // Adjust the timeout as needed

                    // Enable logging
                    client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;

                    try
                    {
                        client.Send(message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to send email: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried using `client.EnableSsl = false;` and `client.EnableSsl = true;` but same issues, i have a SLL certificate(paid if you ask). I my cpanel i have port and server for ssl or nt and i tried using both of them, but no help. I was expecting a email in my inbox, but always errors.

Comment: i fotgot to say that i am calling it this way: `SendEmail(txtUsername.Texts);`